# What pygame event is for the mouse scrolling

Tags: python, pygame

I want to know what event to use in Pygame to scroll with a mouse. For example, if I wrote

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == #event for scrolling with mouse:
        print("hello")
```

I could not find any answers on youtube so I tried this. I am expecting an event name like pygame.QUIT or something like that.